# password remembered clear or bypass

Tags: rhel, password, pam

in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` I have

```
 password    requisite     pam_pwhistory.so use_authtok remember=12
```

as an admin I want to work on a user's account by resetting their password to something like *Temporary1!* so I can log in under their account to troubleshoot a problem.  But when done I want to allow the user to reset their password from that temporary one back to the one they were using.  I don't want to force them to have to use a new password.

Is there a way to clear the `password remembered` for just one specific user?  Rather than commenting out my pam.d entry for that brief moment they reset their password.  I am ok with clearing the remembered ones completely, but for just that user, is there a way to do that?  This is RHEL/CentOS 7.9.

Answer (score 1):

What you **could** do is copy the user's hashed password from `/etc/shadow` and save it somewhere. Change the password and do what you have to. After you're done, you can manually re-insert the old password back into `/etc/shadow`. I'm not sure of the whole scenario, but this will work.